# JQuery Not Able To Find Select List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't, for the life of me, work out why JQuery can't find the select list in this code.  I've tried accessing Select elements in a few JQuery test pages, and it always seems fine, but this just doesn't do anything:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>


    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var new_options = ['were filled with rocks', 'smelled like chicken pox', 'belonged to angry green crocs', 'are kept in a mouldy box' ];

        /* Remove all options from the select list */
        $( "#activity_1" ).empty();

        /* Insert the new ones from the array above */    
        $.each(new_options, function(value) {
        $( "#activity_1" ).append($('<option>', {value: 'Testing', text : 'Testing'}));
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id='#activity_1'><option value='dud'>This shouldn't be here</option</select>,
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the validity of your markup. It seems the `<option>` tag is not closed properly.

Comment: also you have a comma in your html (see after select)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<select id='#activity_1'><
       //   ^
```

to

```
 <select id='activity_1'><
```

your selector  `$('#activity')` searches for an element with the id "activity" not "#activity"

Comment: This is exactly the problem.  Head, meet desk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the colon using two back-slashes:

```
$( "#\\#activity_1" ).empty();
```

replace below also.

```
$.each(new_options, function(value) {
    $( "#\\#activity_1" ).append($('<option>', {value: 'Testing', text : 'Testing'}));
});
```

Edit :

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: . For example, if you have an element with id="#foobar", you can use the selector $("#\#foobar"). The W3C CSS specification contains the complete.

[Jquery selector API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Or either use element `id` such that it must not contain any meta characters.